# How to arrange list of mp4 files in folders?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to recreate MX Player. I just load all mp4 file from storage device, then allocate it to recyclerview.
I also allow to sort these files into folders. When user sort it into folder, no i can't manage to do it.
[screenshot of list recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwft0.png)

**What i want when user sort it into folders is.**

- Show a recyclerview with Folder image, name and no of videos in that folder.
- When user click on folder then list of videos belong to that folder
  should appear.
  [screenshot of folder recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kciT.png)

**Code:** To Retrieve mp4 file from storage device.

```
    private void getFile(File directory) {
    //Get all file in storage
    //directory = new File("/mnt/");
    File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();
    //check storage is empty or not
    if(fileList != null && fileList.length > 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++)
        {
            //check file is directory or other file
            if(fileList[i].isDirectory())
            {
                //if directory than go inside until find file instead of directory
                getFile(fileList[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                //Check the type of file
                if(fileList[i].getName().endsWith(".mp4"))
                {
                    uniqe_video = true;
                    //check file is already listed or not
                    for(int j=0; j<videoArrayList.size(); j++)
                    {
                        if(videoArrayList.get(j).getName().equals(fileList[i].getName())){
                            //File is already listed in videoArrayList
                            uniqe_video = false;
                        }
                    }

                    //First time videoArrayList will be empty. Second time code inside above for loop will be run
                    if(uniqe_video)
                    {
                        videoArrayList.add(fileList[i]);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**
All Path of mp4 file is in videoArrayList.

Example of Path:

> /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/eb3835334286a809a737d0ce3e2276ad.mp4
>   /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/261b66adccd353f1894e14ea51c3efba.mp4
>   /mnt/sdcard/SHAREit/videos/Asim_Azhar_-_Jo_Tu_Na_Mila_(_720_X_1280_).mp4
>   /mnt/sdcard/SHAREit/videos/Luka_Chuppi__Duniyaa_Video_Song___Kartik_Aaryan_Kriti_Sanon___Akhil___Dhvani.mp4
>
> /mnt/sdcard/Videos/Stress is KILLING You _ This is WHY and What You
>   Can Do _ Dr. Joe Dispenza (Eye _HD.mp4

Comment: you probably need not a list of files, but a tree of files. Use tree and show all the nodes of the current node in the `RecyclerView`

Comment: Can you send link of tutorial for this.

Comment: I do not want a complete tree of folder. Mean folder inside folder. I just want a folder and file(mp4) inside it.

Comment: I just take some lecture of tree. But i think i didn't need it. Because they all have root node and then sub-node and sub-nodes. What i need is list of folders and list of files inside it. Each folder has it's own. Not like folder inside folder.

Comment: Can you suggest me how can i do this? If it is possible through tree then how?